# XAML Overriding ToString

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml

I have the following in my ViewModel

```
    public IEnumerable<win8Chores.Model.databaseTables.Person> selectAllPerson()
    {
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {

            return db.Query<win8Chores.Model.databaseTables.Person>("select personId,personName,personEmail,personDOB from Person");
            //return db.Table<Person>();
        }
    }
```

I have a Model:

```
    public class Person
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int personId { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(25)]
        public string personName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string personEmail { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(13)]
        public string personPhone { get; set; }
        public DateTime personDOB { get; set; }
        public Boolean isPersonActive { get; set; }

    }
```

In my View I have the following:

```
        DataContext = VM;
        test.ItemsSource = VM.selectAllPerson();
```

Now originally I was getting in my listview (test) very generic text :

> win8.Model.databaseTables+Person

But then when I added the following to my Model:

```
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} - {1} : {2} -- {3}", personName, personEmail, personPhone, personDOB);
        }
```

Then I got the actual values from the table.

My question is why did I have to `override` the `ToString` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this is the normal behavior of WPF if/when you have not specified how the databound object (an instance of `Person` in your case) should be formatted/displayed. There are multiple ways to address this, one of which might be to simply specify a value for `DisplayMemberPath` to your `ListView`. So for instance, if you don't want to override `ToString()` then you could just create a member property in your `Person` class which returns the desired string and specify it as the `DisplayMemberPath`.

**Person with Summary**

```
public class Person
{
    public int personId { get; set; }
    public string personName { get; set; }
    public string personEmail { get; set; }
    public string personPhone { get; set; }
    public DateTime personDOB { get; set; }
    public Boolean isPersonActive { get; set; }

    public string Summary
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} - {1} : {2} -- {3}", personName, personEmail, personPhone, personDOB); }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ListView ... DisplayMemberPath="Summary"/>
```

**Another (pure XAML) option...**

Alternatively, you could use a custom `DataTemplate` in your `ListView` and specify a `MultiBinding` to provide the desired aggregate value. This approach avoids the need to introduce the new member on you `Person` class.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1} : {2} -- {3}">
                                    <Binding Path="personName" />
                                    <Binding Path="personEmail" />
                                    <Binding Path="personPhone" />
                                    <Binding Path="personDOB" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer.  Just what I was looking for!  Thanks